# Phantom's estimation feature shows my fungible token as NFT?

Tags: token, phantom

The issue came when I deployed my token and my program in Solana devnet. Specifically, I utilized metaplex to deploy the fungible token called Lamas Finance (LMF), whose token standard is Fungible and total supply (amount) is 10M. In the Phantom wallet, the token is shown with right detail and in the right place (not wrongly moved to Collectibles - picture 1)

[image]

However, when I run my Solana program (a simple program for claiming free LMF tokens) and sign the transaction by the Phantom wallet, the estimation feature of Phantom shows the wrong information that LMF (which actually is a fungible token) is NFT (picture 2).

[image]

This is a critical issue because users will definitely confuse when they see this information. My question is how to solve this wrong metadata issue on Phantom.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you set the `uri` field when creating the Metaplex metadata account for your token. You need update the metadata account and set the `uri` to an empty string.

Comment: It works, great.
But another issue came because deleting the URI make the token logo disappear on the Phantom wallet. Do you know any method to solve both issues :D